# Continuity on two variable functions

Tags: calculus, continuity

I'm wondering if there's difference in saying a function with two variables being continuous for each variables and it's continuous for both variables?

if so, what is the case for something like

$$(x,t)\mapsto sin(x t)e^{-x},      t\in \mathbb{R},x\in[0,\infty)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in fact a [difference](http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Separately_continuous_not_implies_continuous#Example).  For example, we can take the function
$$
f(x,y) := \left\lbrace \begin{array}{rl} \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2} & (x,y) \ne (0,0) \\ 0 & (x,y) = (0,0) \\\end{array}\right.
$$
Your particular example, however, is both continuous in each variable separately and a continuous function overall.

Comment: So when ppl say a multi-variable function is continuous, which continuity are they refering to?

Comment: generally, continuity on both variables (rather than on each separately).